# Real time video uploading (getMediaRecorder) to the server

Tags: socket.io, webrtc, mediastream, web-mediarecorder

What is the best way to upload video to the server ?
Currently during recording we receiving chunks, and trying to do an uploading with socket.io which is create a lot of issue.

I wondering is it possible to stream from browser to server with webRTC somehow ? or maybe there is more elegant way to transfer video to the server in real time ?

Answer (score 0):

You can send local video stream to remote server by webrtc, local video include local camera video, screen sharing and [HTMLMediaElement.captureStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/captureStream)

Here is whole exsample for send local camera stream and  video element to remote:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    // display local video file
    <video id="video_file" src="./assets/sample-mp4-file.mp4" loop controls></video>
    <br/>
    // trigger start to send local camera video
    <button id="send_camera">send local camera video</button>
    <div id="remote_video" style="width: 480px; height: 360px;"></div>
    <script>let p1, p2;
        function playRemoteVideo(track) {
            var ele = document.createElement('video');
            ele.srcObject = new MediaStream([track]);
            ele.autoplay = true;
            document.getElementById('remote_video').appendChild(ele)

        }
        async function sendByWebRTC(track) {
            p1 = new RTCPeerConnection({
                iceServers: [
                    {
                        urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302',
                    },
                ],
            });
            p2 = new RTCPeerConnection({
                iceServers: [
                    {
                        urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302',
                    },
                ],
            });

            p2.ontrack = (e) => {
                console.log('remote peer have track', e);
                playRemoteVideo(e.track)
            };

            // ensure exchange candidate
            p1.onicecandidate = (e) => {
                if (!!e.candidate) {
                    p2.addIceCandidate(e.candidate);
                }
            };
            p2.onicecandidate = (e) => {
                if (!!e.candidate) {
                    p1.addIceCandidate(e.candidate);
                }
            };

            // add local video track to 
            p1.addTrack(track);
            let offer = await p1.createOffer({
                offerToReceiveAudio: false,
                offerToReceiveVideo: false,
            });
            await p1.setLocalDescription(offer);

            await p2.setRemoteDescription(offer);

            let answer = await p2.createAnswer({
                offerToReceiveAudio: false,
                offerToReceiveVideo: false,
            });
            await p2.setLocalDescription(answer);
            await p1.setRemoteDescription(answer);
        }

        window.onload = function () {
            // bind event to send video element to remote
            document.getElementById('video_file').addEventListener('play', () => {
                console.log('play video file')
                var track = document.getElementById('video_file').captureStream().getVideoTracks()[0]
                sendByWebRTC(track)
            })
            // bind event to send local camera video to remote
            document.getElementById('send_camera').addEventListener('click', () => {
                // send local camera to remote
                navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(stream => {
                    var track = stream.getVideoTracks()[0]
                    sendByWebRTC(track)
                })
            })
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

- Click video control.play will send video element to remote.
- Click button 'send local camera video' will send local camera to remote.